# angular directives, controllerAs and scope properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this code for my directive (based on http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-6-using-controllers)

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myButton',function(){

        var controller = function () {
              var vm = this;

              console.log("label",vm.saveLabel);
        };

        return {
            replace: true,
            restrict: 'E',

            scope: {
                cancelLabel: '@',
                saveLabel: '@'
            },

            template: '<p>Label: {{vm.saveLabel}}</p>',

            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController: true
        };
});
```

and this html

```
<my-button saveLabel="Save"></my-button>
```

however, the saveLabel value is always undefined

I can't see what I'm missing. I know it's something stupid ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
<my-button saveLabel="Save"></my-button>
```

as

```
<my-button save-label="Save"></my-button>
```

right from [AngularJs Directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) :

> **Note** : These `=attr` attributes in the scope option of directives are normalized just like directive names. To bind to the attribute in
>   `<div bind-to-this="thing">`, you'd specify a binding of
>   `=bindToThis`.

Comment: right in front of my face. I managed to normalise the element name, but forgot about the attribute name. Thanks. Feeling stupid, but thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/sLtsGW0Os0jqFt070xc7?p=preview**

Use it like:

```
<my-button save-label="Save"></my-button>
<!-- Or you can use like -->
<my-button data-save-label="Save"></my-button>
<!--But not like the following -->
<!-- <my-button savelLabel="Save"></my-button> -->
```

Angularjs uses **Normalization:**

Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. We typically refer to directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g. ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

The normalization process is as follows:

> **1.** Strip x- and data- from the front of the element/attributes.
>
> **2.** Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.